# Backtrace with function-name,file-name and line-no information

Tags: linux, backtrace

We have an application software running on Suse linux. What I want is that whenever there is a crash/fault in the software, a backtrace is generated with call stack information for the current thread(which faults).
We are currently using "backtrace()" and "backtrace_symbols_fd()" to try to get the trace but there is not much useful information. It does not give function names, line no. and filename. 
Therefore, I starting looking for alternate options to use and found "libunwind". Wrote a small function to get backtrace and it does print function name with other register values(ip,sp). But still I can not get the filename and linenumbers. Is there a way I can programmatically do that ? What happens if I strip my binary file? Can I still get the filename/lineno info ?

Comment: I am not sure if calling "addr2line" for each of the addresses returned from either backtrace() or libunwind api is a good idea.